# No more F/1.2 primes?

Tags: lens, aperture

A question from my dad:

“Back in my day, all the cool kids used f/1.2 primes. Is there a reason why they don't make those any more?”

If I had to *guess*, I'd take a stab that digital sensors don't require quite so much light, negating the need to produce f/1.2 lenses (which must surely be really awkward to design and expensive to manufacture). But I don't *really* know... Does anybody have any more authoritative information?

Comment: Are you sure your dad remembers right? I believe 1.2 lenses have always been a little rarer; I'd say all the cool kids shot/shoot f1.4 primes. There are a few 1.2 lenses made still, too.

Comment: @DanWolfgang It is of course possible that my dad doesn't remember this stuff as well as he thinks he does. ;-)

Comment: A quick search shows they still do. Here are all [current F/1.2 prime lenses](http://www.neocamera.com/search_lens.php?aperturemax=1.2%3Amax&prime=1&by=feature).

Comment: @Itai Not one of those is for Nikon F-mount. (Although I'm sure I have seen one somewhere. Emphasis *one*.) And besides, I get the impression [which may or may not be accurate] that there used to be quite a range of these things, whereas now they only make a few. Obviously I wasn't around back when my dad is talking about, so...

Comment: According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nikon_F-mount there have only ever been three Nikon f1.2 lenses.

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid - Read your question twice and still don't know where your comment about Nikon F-mount is coming from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They still make f/1.2 primes.

Canon has both the 50/1.2L and the 85/1.2L. Nikon hasn't updated it in a while, but they still offer a 50/1.2. Fuji makes a 56mm f/1.2 (85e) for the X system; and Panasonic/Leica makes a 42.5 (85e) f/1.2 for mft.

But what The Cool Kids (well, at least those who are big aperture nuts) are using these days are f/0.95 primes. :)

Micro four-thirds, in particular, is riddled with f/0.95 3rd-party lenses, mostly because the smaller sensor size means that using 1" video lenses can be a possibility. Even Voigtlander makes an f/0.95 25mm and 17.5mm options for mft.

Comment: Olympus also announced a new 25mm f/1.2 for MFT just last week, amusingly enough :)

Answer (score 1):

Leica still makes the noctilux lenses which open even further than 1.2, good luck focusing that thing, given that you sold your left arm to get one (maybe the shallow depth of field makes things difficult, too)

Canon has a 85mm 1.2 lens which due to the heavy glass that moves around has somewhat limited auto focus performance. Rumours have it they are working on a new version, but I guess such a lens will always remain a speciality tool. Handling it requires more skill.

The cool kids are also doing video these days.
Trading a maximum aperture for image stabilisation is a viable option even for stills photographers if applicable. The popular high quality zoom lenses are offered with both 2.8 and 4 + stabilisation side by side by some manufacturers. There's demand for both. This is a bit far fetched for an argument for 1.2 primes, but it shows in what direction the market is going.

There are lenses that have a larger max apertures for smaller sized sensors, but that's not a fair comparison.